# New line in node.js mailer template

Tags: node.js, mailer

I'm using node.js mailer module to send email from node server. I used template file for that but I got all spaces trimmed when the message was sent. I tried to add '\n' at the end line of the template but it doesn't work also. Here is an example of template file:

```
Hi {{username}},\\n

Thanks for creating an account with us
```

I tried \n and \n , nothing all doesn't work. Any help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known behavior, mustache is made to work with HTML templates, in HTML, new lines will be contracted as one space only.

You can try doing something like `{{new_line}}` instead your `\\n`, and define `new_line: "\n\xA0"` in your datas. `\xA0` is the non-breakable space, it can separate line if you want to make two new lines.

An other solution is to not use the template, but just get the content of the file as text with `fs.readFileSync(filename)` and use a regexp to replace `{{xxx}}` by an object content.

Comment: This doesn't work. All it does is it adds a regular space not a new line. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: From what I remember, by default node-mailer is sending mail in html, and maybe can convert html to text. So try in your template to put some `<br />` to make a new line, it should work.

Comment: I mustache you a question

Answer (score 5):

`nodemailer` supports two types of templates, i.e. `text` and `html (or templateFn() - case of loopback)`.

The option `text` is used for email clients which don't support HTML rendering so that `\n` should be used in this option for a new line.

On the contrary, you should swap `\n` with `<br>` in the option `html`.

Hope this would help you.