# Nodemailer does not send the text with line breaks

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am using [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) which is a NodeJS module for sending mails. However, it does not send the mails with line breaks but I have tried to print out the variable that contains the text I am trying to send and there are line breaks.

I get the text I write in a text area:

[image]

`site.js:`

```
$("#send-mail").click(function(){
    $.post("/sendMail",{fieldHeader: $('#field-header').val()}, function(data){
        window.location.href ="/";
    });
});
```

`server.js:`

```
app.post('/sendMail', function(req, res) {
    mailSender.init(req.body.fieldHeader);
});
```

`mailSender.js`

```
function init(fieldHeader) {
    console.log(fieldHeader);
    if(fieldHeader!=null) {
        var mailer = require("nodemailer");

        var smtpTransport = mailer.createTransport({
            host: "smtp.gmail.com",
            service: "Gmail",
            tls:{
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            },
            auth: {
                user: "...",
                pass: "..."
            }
        });

        var mail = {
            from: "...",
            to: "...",
            subject: "Send Email Using Node.js",
            text: "Node.js New world for me",
            html: fieldHeader
        }

        smtpTransport.sendMail(mail, function(error, response){
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
            }else{
                console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
            }

            smtpTransport.close();
        });
    }
}
module.exports.init = init;
```

As I said, I print out the variable that contains the text I want to send in the mail (it's the console.log() you see at the beggining of the `mailSender.js`) and this is the result:

[image]

But the received mail, does not contain any line break:
[image]

I have been thinking about replacing the line breaks with `<br>` using a loop that would look and check each character in the text, but I am not sure if it is a good idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New line in node.js mailer template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226390/new-line-in-node-js-mailer-template)

Comment: Maybe try $('#field-header').html()  instead of .val()

Comment: I've tried with .hml() and apparently it only gets its value with .val(). 

But I've managed to solve it. I was sending the text in the html property but I deleted that and I put it in the text property instead and it works now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding break tags where you want line breaks. `<br>` or `<br />`

```
var fieldheader = `hi <br> how are you ? <br> this is testing <br>`
var mail = {
    from: "...",
    to: "...",
    subject: "Send Email Using Node.js",
    text: "Node.js New world for me",
    html: fieldHeader
}
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes but I cannot use this as ```fileheader``` is a variable that contains the text I write in a textarea field. So it will not always have the same value. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then it is better to use `ckediter` instead of simple text editor . because in ckeditor you will get the data with html format so it will work for you .

Comment: I've looked for ```ckeditor``` but I've managed to fix my issue easier. I was sending the text in the html property but I deleted that and I put it in the text property instead and it works now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Welcome . Happy to help you . @AdriánT95

Comment: Yes this works, but isn't this an HTML break, what if we want a plain TEXT line break, i.e., in the line: `text: "Node.js New world \n for me"`. This won't work, or would it?

Answer (score 3):

Just put `\n` where you want a line break.